# Java cannot find a specific method on a seperate file

Tags: java, visual-studio, oop, object

Im using Visual Studio Code, and I just create a folder with the "project" inside, i dont like to use netbeans, eclipse, etc for small programs.

So I'm creating a small program, that i doubted would work, but it did for the mos part, it creates a rpg like character and a 2nd one and creates a simulated battle in which one character wins based on one stat. Everything seems to work but when I call the method `Battle(oumar, aisha);`, which takes two characters and has them battle, it gets an error saying 
`Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Battle(oumar, aisha);
        ^
  symbol:   method Battle(Character,Character)
  location: class Main`

So since im not so experienced im not sure what the problem really is.
Here is the code for the main class:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Character oumar = new Character("Oumar", 10);
        Character aisha = new Character("Aisha", 9);
        Battle(oumar, aisha);

    }


}
```

and here is the second class within a seperate file (still in the same folder)

```
public class Character {

    String name;
    int BattlePower;
    int wins;
    Character one;
    Character two;

    public Character(String name, int BattlePower) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wins = wins;
        System.out.println("New character: "+ name);
        this.BattlePower = BattlePower;
        this.wins = wins;
        System.out.println(name + "has a Battle Power of " + BattlePower);
    }

    public void Battle(Character one, Character two) {

        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;

        if (one.BattlePower > two.BattlePower ) {
            System.out.print("Character " + one + " has won the Battle!");
            one.wins++;
            System.out.print("Character one now has " + wins + " wins!");
        }
        else if (two.BattlePower > one.BattlePower) {
            System.out.print("Character " + two + " has won the Battle!");
            two.wins++;
            System.out.print("Character two now has " + wins + " wins!");
        }
        else {

            System.out.print("The two characters have tied!");

        }    
    }    
}
```

Any help would be great, as well as any tips that might help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use

`oumar.Battle(oumar, aisha)`

or

`aisha.Battle(oumar, aisha)`

as the method is inside of a non static class so it can't be called without an object reference.

If you want to call it like

`Battle(oumar, aisha)`

you'll need to move it to the main class.

Also, this issue should be present on those other IDEs as well.

Comment: Thanks very much i feel like an idiot, of course a method within an object class needs to be called by the object (not sure if i worded that properly) but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can put a no-arg constructor inside the Character class like public Character(){}. Then in the Main.java you can use the no-arg constructor to create an object of the Character class and then invoke the method Battle like Character ch1 = new Character(); ch1.Battle(oumar,aisha).

Comment: Thanks this helped, but im just wondering what would i put inside of this constructor, and do i keep the original one?

Comment: You have to put nothing inside the constructor and you can keep the original one. This is constructor overload ing feature of java.